# NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN Macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am following an online tutorial from team tree house and one of the steps is to create an NSManagedObject subclass for my data model.

When I did that the code automatically generated a class and set of macros at the beginning and and the end:

**NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN**

**NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END**

I was searching online but I could not find any documentation about what these guys are doing here. By the way they were defined in the header **NSObjCRuntime.h**

Any ideas what purpose they serve?

Comment: like I said not a lot of documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/ns_assume_nonnull_begin All I see is a lot of issues and how to troubleshoot them but not what's for.

Comment: See [Nullability and Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID45) in the _Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C_ guide.

Comment: "Not a lot of documentation" is regrettable, but it's the *second* hit. Try the first: [Nullability and Objective-C - Swift Blog - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It's a convenience macro to save you typing **nonnull** in your headers.  From the *Swift* blog detailing how new safety features have been incorporated back in *Objective-C*:

> To ease adoption of the new annotations, you can mark certain regions
>   of your Objective-C header files as audited for nullability. Within
>   these regions, any simple pointer type will be assumed to be nonnull.

See Nullability and Objective-C - https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25